# Writing Foreign Languages In XSL-FO

Tags: xml, pdf, xsl-fo

I'm trying to generate a PDF using XSL-FO markup, to replace an XML-Word document.  The original document used hexidecimal coding and tags to write characters in foreign languages, such as chinese characters.  I need to duplicate these characters in XSL-FO, but my experience with it is lackluster at best.

How can I write these foreign language characters into my XSL-FO document?

EDIT: I've discovered that its' not "Hexidecimal" code I'm looking for, but Unicode.  And I've found a site that looks like it is helpful in this endeavor.

http://www.antennahouse.com/XSLsample/multi.htm

This should be helpful to anyone trying to write foreign characters in XSL-FO.

Comment: Can you show us some examples of "hexidecimal coding and tags"?

Comment: 0409000F

After doing more research and looking into it a bit further, it's Unicode, not "hexidecimal" as I originally said.  

And, I've actually found something that looks like it will be helpful.

http://www.antennahouse.com/XSLsample/multi.htm

Adding this to my original question for ease of reference.  Sorry I didn't add this sooner, converting these docs, coupled with being under the weather, has had me swamped.